# RAE vs IU in Vitamin descriptions

Tags: micronutrients, measurement, labeling

Reading an article about Vitamin-A:

[Vitamin A
Fact Sheet for Health Professionals](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminA-HealthProfessional/)

The following acronym `RAE` in:

> RDAs for vitamin A are given as mcg of retinol activity equivalents (RAE) to account for the different bioactivities of retinol and provitamin A carotenoids (see Table 1). Because the body converts all dietary sources of vitamin A into retinol, 1 mcg of physiologically available retinol is equivalent to the following amounts from dietary sources: 1 mcg of retinol, 12 mcg of beta-carotene, and 24 mcg of alpha-carotene or beta-cryptoxanthin. From dietary supplements, the body converts 2 mcg of beta-carotene to 1 mcg of retinol.
>
> Currently, vitamin A is listed on food and supplement labels in international units (IUs) even though nutrition scientists rarely use this measure. Conversion rates between mcg RAE and IU are as follows [7]:
>
> 1 IU retinol = 0.3 mcg RAE
> 1 IU beta-carotene from dietary supplements = 0.15 mcg RAE
> 1 IU beta-carotene from food = 0.05 mcg RAE
> 1 IU alpha-carotene or beta-cryptoxanthin = 0.025 mcg RAE

Can you please explain a bit the diffence between those measurements? :)

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE, volna! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. This question is a bit unclear to me, as the quote you posted *should* be the explanation you seek. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you are ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you need help, you can view our [ask] page. If you could detail a bit more what exactly is unclear to you, someone with an answer will do a better job. Thanks!

Comment: IU = international unit, mcg RAE = microgram retinol activity equivalents (old unit). [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinol#Units_of_measurement) explains it a bit.